# How do I pass a log4j configuration to the Eclipse IDE itself?

Tags: eclipse, log4j, xtext

**I'm not trying to configure log4j for an Eclipse project but for the IDE itself!!**

When using Xtext-based plugins, I'm seeing this warning in the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.internal.Activator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How do I supply a log4j configuration to the IDE itself?

I tried adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=.../log4j.properties` to `eclipse.ini`. The entry is visible in About/Configuration and the file path is correct but it's not picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `log4j.properties` has to be on the classpath of the `org.apache.log4j` plugin. Therefore you'll have to provide a bundle fragment that contains your configuration.

Xtext ships with `org.eclipse.xtext.logging` for that reason.

**[EDIT]** So one solution for the warning above is to make sure that the plugin `org.eclipse.xtext.logging` is installed. You can find it on the [official Indigo download site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was install **xText SDK**, from Eclipse repositorie